# Substitute for multiple "When Matched" with Update clause when using Merge in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this Merge statement

```
MERGE Destination d
USING @Source s
    ON d.DestinationId = s.DestinationId

WHEN MATCHED AND (
    ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldOne,0) != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldOne,0) OR
    ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldTwo,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldTwo,'') OR
    ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldThree,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldThree,'') OR
    ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldFour,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldFour,'')

THEN UPDATE SET
    d.DestinationFieldOne = s.DestinationFieldOne,
    d.DestinationFieldTwo = s.DestinationFieldTwo,
    d.DestinationFieldThree = s.DestinationFieldThree,
    d.DestinationFieldFour = s.DestinationFieldFour
WHEN MATCHED AND (
    @Deleted = 1
)
THEN UPDATE SET
    d.Deleted = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (DestinationFieldOne, DestinationFieldTwo, DestinationFieldThree, DestinationFieldFour) VALUES (s.DestinationFieldOne, s.DestinationFieldTwo, s.DestinationFieldThree, s.DestinationFieldFour)
```

It's giving me

> An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a
> 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You'll have to find a way to write a single `UPDATE` that can accommodate both types of changes. Unfortunately we have no idea what the first `UPDATE` is doing. This is a [Well documented restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#when-matched-then-merge_matched)

Comment: I updated the merge statement. The first when match updates all the fields. The second update is to update deleted bit field to 1 or true.

Comment: If you're only updating.... just use an `update` statement

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. Unless you hvae temporal tables or trigger you can just update the columns regardless. If they are different they'll update. If they are the same they'll update but you won't notice. As it is only one column needs to be different to trigger an update of all columns

Comment: The thing is i also make use of the when not matched then insert. i updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is functionally the same as what you've written.

Which is: if @delete=1, only update the deleted column otherwise update all attributes

```
UPDATE Destination
SET 
    -- leave as old values if Deleted=1
    d.DestinationFieldOne =
        IIF(s.Deleted=1,d.DestinationFieldOne,s.DestinationFieldOne),
    d.DestinationFieldTwo = 
        IIF(s.Deleted=1,d.DestinationFieldTwo,s.DestinationFieldTwo),
    d.DestinationFieldThree = 
        IIF(s.Deleted=1,d.DestinationFieldThree,s.DestinationFieldThree),
    d.Deleted = IIF(s.Deleted=1,1,d.Deleted)
FROM Destination d
INNER JOIN @Source s
ON d.DestinationId = s.DestinationId
```

But, if i make some bold assumptions about what's in `@Source`, I suspect this is fine:

```
UPDATE Destination
SET 
    d.DestinationFieldOne = s.DestinationFieldOne,
    d.DestinationFieldTwo = s.DestinationFieldTwo,
    d.DestinationFieldThree = s.DestinationFieldThree,
    d.Deleted = s.Deleted
FROM Destination d
INNER JOIN @Source s
ON d.DestinationId = s.DestinationId


INSERT INTO Destination (
DestinationFieldOne, DestinationFieldTwo, 
DestinationFieldThree, DestinationFieldFour) 
SELECT s.DestinationFieldOne, s.DestinationFieldTwo, 
s.DestinationFieldThree, s.DestinationFieldFour
FROM @Source S WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Destination D WHERE S.DestinationId = D.DestinationId
    )
```

Comment: Strictly, the current attempt in the question doesn't make clear what should happen if both `@Delete` is `1` and some or all of those columns differ. Both `WHEN` clauses appear to match then and more hilarity ensues.

Comment: How do I add this to my merge statement?

Comment: It replaces your merge statement completely. Merge actually has a lot of issues and personally I avoid using it

Comment: The thin is I also make use of the not matched statement to insert. I updated my post

Comment: I have edited and added an insert statement. In future please describe the whole question at the start

Answer (score 0):

If either @Deleted or the other long condition, update all 5 columns:

```
UPDATE d set
     DestinationFieldOne    = case DestinationUpdateFlag when 1 then s.DestinationFieldOne      else d.DestinationFieldOne      end         
    ,DestinationFieldTwo    = case DestinationUpdateFlag when 1 then s.DestinationFieldTwo      else d.DestinationFieldTwo      end     
    ,DestinationFieldThree  = case DestinationUpdateFlag when 1 then s.DestinationFieldThree    else d.DestinationFieldThree    end
    ,DestinationFieldFour   = case DestinationUpdateFlag when 1 then s.DestinationFieldFour     else d.DestinationFieldFour     end
    ,Deleted                = case @Deleted when 1 then 1 else d.Deleted end
from 
    Destination d
    INNER JOIN @Source s ON d.DestinationId = s.DestinationId
    cross apply
    (select case when 
        ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldOne,0) != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldOne,0) OR
        ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldTwo,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldTwo,'') OR
        ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldThree,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldThree,'') OR
        ISNULL(d.DestinationFieldFour,'') != ISNULL(s.DestinationFieldFour,'')
    then 1 else 0 end as DestinationUpdateFlag
    ) as q1
where @Deleted = 1 or DestinationUpdateFlag=1
```

Comment: I'm trying this? how do i put this in my existing merge statement?

Comment: You don't put in the `merge` statement. You forget about `merge`, and just run this.

Comment: the thing is I also make use of the when not matched for insertion i made an edit on my post